# Text API intergration issue - Error 405 page not found

Tags: c#, .net, sms, sms-gateway

I am using Innovative Text SMS API gateway which is through me error.

Documentation is available at link http://www.innovativetxt.com/services/sms_api_gateway.htm, the error is happening on my local machine, but works fine at the production server.

The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

at this line of code:

HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

```
try
{
// InnovativeTXT POST URL
string url = "http://innovativetxt.com/cp/api";
// XML-formatted data
string toSender = "4477878585244";
string fromSender = "Test";
string textMessage = "Thanks for Choosing Innovative Text Messaging Solution.";

string fields = "?to=" + toSender + "&from=" + fromSender + "&text=" + textMessage +     "&api_key=xxx&api_secret=xxxxx";
url = url + fields;
// web request start
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
string data = "field-keywords=ASP.NET 2.0";
if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
{
// create a request on behalf of uri
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);    
// setting parameter for the request
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// a stream writer for the request
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
// write down the date
writer.Write(data);
//close the stream writer
writer.Close();

// getting response from the request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

// Get the stream associated with the response.
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

// to write a http response from the characters
Response.Write(readStream.ReadToEnd());
// close the response
response.Close();
// close the reader
readStream.Close();
}
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
// catch for unhelded exception
Response.Write(exp.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue relates to IIS Handler mappings.

You should specify the file name at the end of string URL:

```
string url = "http://innovativetxt.com/cp/api/somepage.aspx";
```

You can use default pages like, `default.aspx` or `index.php` etc...